# Why controllers need instance variables to use ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, railstutorial.org

In [chapter 12.2.5](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-a_working_follow_button_with_ajax) of the rails tutorial, Ajax is introduced in order to "send requests asynchronously to the server without leaving the page". The `respond_to` method is then used in the controller to allow browsers with enabled javascript to use Ajax or to respond with a redirect in case Ajax is disabled.

The form used to create a relationship between two users is:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.active_relationships.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The corresponding action in the relationships controller is:

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(@user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

What gives Rails the opportunity to use Ajax is the addition of `remote: true` in the `form_for` helper method. According to the tutorial, it is necessary for the controller to use the instance variable `@user` instead of the local variable `user` for use in the form with `remote: true`.

Without Ajax, the resulting form would be identical except for the `remote: true` code absence, and in the controller the `respond_to` section of code would be replaced by a redirect_to; moreover, the instance variable `@user` can be replaced by the local variable `user`, so that the create action would be:

```
  def create
    user = User.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_user.follow(user)
    redirect_to user
  end
```

I am wondering: why it is necessary for the controller to use the `@user` instance variable instead of the local variable `user` in order to use Ajax? I tried to use the local variable, and in effect a refresh is required to see any change. The `@user` variable in the form, which is used in `@user.id`, is defined in the show action for the users controller, because the partial for the form itself is inserted in the `show.html.erb` file. So, as far as I understand, there is no connection between `@user` in the users controller and `@user` in the relationships controller.

Comment: For the record I was wondering the exact same thing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare it as instance variable (@) so it will be available in your view. Yes, using ajax you are not reloading the page, but you are sending back js instead of html. rails will respond with whatever is in `create.js.erb`. Notice that in this file you need access to the @user data; if you declare it as `user` instead of `@user`, it will not be accessible:

```
#app/views/relationships/create.js.erb
$("#follow_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/unfollow')) %>");
$("#followers").html('<%= @user.followers.count %>');
```

Comment: Thanks. It makes much more sense now.